# REST PUT is that ok without key in the uri? instead put the key inside the body?

Tags: rest

I am designing a REst API. our backend resource object has a combination as key, like account_number+product_type.

is that ok for PUT to update an account, use this
PUT: /accounts

```
{

account_number:1222;

product_type:sn,

;;;;

}
```

I know standard way to use PUT with reference key in the uri, just wondering if without key will occur any issues?

Comment: Technically there won’t be any issue. But you should follow the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is that ok for PUT to update an account, use this PUT: /accounts

The potential problem is that the request doesn't mean what you think it does.

One of the constraints in the REST architectural style is uniform interface constraint; broadly, that means that everybody understands requests the same way.

PUT, in HTTP, is defined to mean: replace the state of the target resource with the representation enclosed in the message body of the http request.  See [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.

In other words, when you create a request like

```
PUT  /accounts

{ "account_number":1222, ...
```

You are saying that you want this block of JSON to be the thing returned when somebody sends a `GET /accounts` request.

What you probably want, from the your question, is to leave `/accounts` unchanged, and to actually be making changes to the `/accounts/1222` resource.  But that's not what *this* request says.

The danger is not that your server will do the wrong thing - you control your server, and the server has a great deal of freedom about what it does in response to a request.

The real danger is that other general purpose components will do the wrong thing, because they will believe that the message means what it says it means, and not some other thing that only your server understands.

If the resulting confusion results in loss of property, everybody is going to (correctly) blame your server for its incorrect interpretation of the message semantics.

What kind of confusion are we talking about?  The specification of [204 No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) offers a hint: the client (and any other general purpose components) are permitted to assume that the meta data included in the 204 response apply to the *target resource*, which is to say the resource identified by the target-uri; in this example, the meta data will be applied to `/accounts` instead of the `/accounts/1222`.

Certainly, such a design is faulty; the fault may or may not lead to a failure.

In a project I maintained, I would immediately reject a pull-request when I discovered this fault.  It's right up there with needless breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: thanks. this explains very clear what the issue will occur.